# Maximum distance (gap) possible b/w two athletes when they are running infinitely in a circle of fixed radius

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, circles, wave-equation, circular-motion

There are two athletes (say A & B) - starting from same fixed point-running with speed X m/s and Y m/s around a circle of radius R in anti-clockwise direction - infinitely. How can I find the maximum distance difference possible b/w the runners throughout their infinite run?

The reset of the distance happens when the athletes overlap (whenever one of them overtakes)

For e.g.:

A and B = 7m/s and 5 m/s with radius 0.79m - after 1 lap the distance difference would be dx1 - A is ahead by some amount - since its faster and in the next round it will increase....

What can be the maximum distance difference (along the circular arc) possible in an infinite run?

Note: The distance shall be measured in anti-clockwise direction - the direction in which runners are running

Comment: Do you really have a circle with r=0.79 so the 7m/s runner goes around in 0,7s and the 5m/s runner in a little less than 1s?

Comment: Does the distance reset once the faster runner overtakes? Otherwise it's equivalent to a line. It can also be good to show some working - what have you already tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @trula as an example, yes. but i am interested in generalized solution. - so, the radius and speed can be anything

Comment: @George : thank you the question. i will edit it - yes - reset happens when any one of them "overlap" - haven't found any mathematical solution yet -  but  some "not so good" programming solution- like run laps again and again and compute the difference per lap and find max after certain while  - no concrete solution yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the speeds are the same, then the runners distance will be 0 (or the starting value if they aren't).

If the speeds are different, then at some point one runner will overtake the next runner (since they run for an infinite amount of time): right before this point, the runners will be just a little bit under the full circumference away from each other (slightly less than $2\pi r$ for $r$ the radius, measured in the direction they're running).

Now if we think about the maximum possible value, we can see that it's also the full circumference ($2 \pi r$- anything larger would be more than a full lap).

So we never actually reach the maximum length, but we can get arbitrarily close to it: for $r$ the radius, and any small distance $\varepsilon > 0$, then there will be a moment (very shortly before overtaking) that the runners are $2 \pi r - \varepsilon$ distance apart.

##### Edit - Number of laps/amount of time before this happens:

Without loss of generality assume A is faster than B, A travelling at speed $a$, B at speed $b$. Then you can view this as A travelling at speed $a-b$ faster than B with B stationary (imagine that you are watching from B's perspective), so that A overtakes B at

$$
\textrm{time} = \dfrac{\textrm{distance}}{\textrm{speed}} = \dfrac{2 \pi r}{a-b}
$$

time into the race, so that in that time A has travelled a total of $a \cdot\dfrac{2 \pi r}{a-b}$ distance, and then dividing by the length of a lap ($2\pi r$) to get number of laps (effectively changing unit of distance from meters to laps), we get that A overtakes B after exactly
$$
\dfrac{a}{a-b} \  \quad \textrm{laps.}
$$

(And similarly, B should have made one less lap, or
$$
\dfrac{a}{a-b} - 1 = \dfrac{a-(a-b)}{a-b} = \dfrac{b}{a-b}
$$
which can be found in the same way after calculating the amount of time and multiplying it by B's speed)

Comment: Thank you ! this seems straightforward. By any chance would you happen to know the calculation for lap no (of either A or B) where this happens

Comment: I just added the calculation in an edit! The idea is you first find the time, from which you can more easily get how many laps A has made.